# Magento2 import error -

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, magento-2.0.2

We are receiving an error when trying to import our product catalog via CSV.

General system exception happened
Additional data: Wrong request parameters

We also get the same error when trying to import the sample file generated by the import page (catalog_product.csv)

Our magento version is 2.0.2

Edit:  Upgraded to 2.0.4 this morning - still receiving the same error.
The strange thing is that validation seems to work, but we receive the "General system exception happened
Additional data: Wrong request parameters" on any file that passes validation, including the default sample file generated by the import page.  It seems like this may be some server setting interfering with request inputs, however, double checking the requirements everything seems to be in order.

Comment: can you share your csv file ?

Comment: link to sample csv that errors out - http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01749612785080796555

Comment: link is not working right now

Comment: Try this - http://www.hobbyrepublic.com/catalog_product.csv

Comment: I also tried with this file,
http://www.hobbyrepublic.com/one_row_test.csv
and got the same error on my production server.  
However, I was successfully able to import the same file on a dev box - this leads me to believe it is a server setting. 

Any idea what server settings / permissions might lead to the General System Exception, or where I can look for a more detailed error?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong request parameters is thrown by google optimiser extension (Magento\GoogleOptimizer\Observer::_initRequestParams()). It seems M2 has new A/B testing and when 'Enable Content Experiments' is enabled then system throws "Wrong request parameters" as it can not find 'google_experiment' parameter.

**Solution is to disable Content Experiments in Store => Configuraiton => Sales => Google Api**

Answer (score 0):

If you have product categories in you import file that do not exist in the Magento installation you are importing to then validation (i.e. Check Data) will pass but importation will fail giving the error *Additional data: Wrong request parameters*

**The solution - create product categories and sub-categories in the destination magento store that match those in the CSV.**